# UpdateView gives blank form in django inline formset

Tags: django, inline, inline-formset

MY CreateView worked fine but when I try to update this form data, it gives blank form. No data was shown. Here is my views.py:

```
@require_authenticated_permission(
'member.add_person')
class PersonCreate( FormsetMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'member/person_form.html'
    model = Person    
    form_class = MemberForm
    formset_class = PersonFormSet

@require_authenticated_permission(
'member.change_person')
class PersonUpdate( FormsetMixin,  UpdateView):
    template_name = 'member/person_form.html'
    model = Person    
    form_class = MemberForm
    formset_class = PersonFormSet
```

Here is my formset:

```
class MemberForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('user',)       

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MemberForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Your full name'
        self.fields['tele_land'].label = 'Land phone'
        self.fields['tele_cell'].label = 'Cell phone'
        self.fields['passing_year'].label = 'Passing year'
        self.fields['passing_year'].help_text = 'According to your session year'


    def save(self, request, commit=True):
        person = super().save(commit=False)
        if not person.pk:
            person.user = get_user(request)
        if commit:
            person.save()
            self.save_m2m()
        return person

class ChildrenForm(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
        model = Children
        fields = '__all__'

PersonFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Person, Children, extra=0, min_num=1, fields=('child_name', 'child_birth_date','blood_group' ))
```

Url:

```
url(r'^person/create/$', views.PersonCreate.as_view(), name='person-create'),

url(r'^person/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/update/$', views.PersonUpdate.as_view(), name='person-update'),
```

My formset mixin:

```
class FormsetMixin(object):
    object = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(self, 'is_update_view', False):
            self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        formset_class = self.get_formset_class()
        formset = self.get_formset(formset_class)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if getattr(self, 'is_update_view', False):
            self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        formset_class = self.get_formset_class()
        formset = self.get_formset(formset_class)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, formset)

    def get_formset_class(self):
        return self.formset_class

    def get_formset(self, formset_class):
        return formset_class(**self.get_formset_kwargs())

    def get_formset_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = {
            'instance': self.object
        }
        if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
            kwargs.update({
                'data': self.request.POST,
                'files': self.request.FILES,
            })
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form, formset):
        self.object = form.save(self.request)
        formset.instance = self.object
        formset.save()
        return redirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, formset):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))
```

Why my UpdateView gives blank form?

Answer (score 0):

Proably because `getattr(self, 'is_update_view', False)` always is false so you're not loading any `self.object`.

I have for similar situations used `ModelFormSetView` from [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views). It's easy to use if you already understand Django class based views and will save you a lot of code to write and maintain yourself.

BTW you should implement `get_queryset` and prefetch the `Children`.

Answer (score 0):

Use in UpdateView: `is_update_view = True`. It will be like

```
class PersonUpdate( FormsetMixin,  UpdateView):
template_name = 'member/person_form.html'
model = Person    
is_update_view = True
form_class = MemberForm
formset_class = PersonFormSet
```